# Yodlee: getMFAResponseForSite does not work for TD Canada Trust

Tags: yodlee

I'm trying to add one of my bank accounts using the TestDrive application on the Yodlee website and the "Flow: Add account" example but I think the MFA functionality is broken for this particular bank. It works fine for another bank account I have but for this one I get the message:
Credential Re-Verification Required (402): We could not update your account because your username and/or password were reported to be incorrect. Please re-verify your username and password.
But there's nothing wrong with the username and password.

It doesn't seem to be able to retrieve the MFA questions.  The example calls getMFAResponseForSite several times and it returns:

```
{
   "isMessageAvailable": false,
   "timeOutTime": 150000,
   "itemId": 0,
   "errorCode": 402,
   "memSiteAccId": 10027626,
   "retry": false
}
```

When I login to the site manually, sometimes it asks me one of five security questions, so I expect that getMFAResponseForSite should return one of these questions so that I can send the answer with putMFAResponseForSite.  Does this mean that Yodlee is not able to retrieve the MFA questions on this site?

Here's the response from getSiteInfo for the account I'm trying to add:

```
 {
  "popularity": 0,
  "siteId": 3521,
  "orgId": 447,
  "defaultDisplayName": "TD Bank (Canada)",
  "defaultOrgDisplayName": "TD Waterhouse",
  "contentServiceInfos": [
    {
      "contentServiceId": 3736,
      "siteId": 3521,
      "containerInfo": {
        "containerName": "bank",
        "assetType": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "contentServiceId": 11037,
      "siteId": 3521,
      "containerInfo": {
        "containerName": "credits",
        "assetType": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "contentServiceId": 21166,
      "siteId": 3521,
      "containerInfo": {
        "containerName": "stocks",
        "assetType": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "contentServiceId": 18274,
      "siteId": 3521,
      "containerInfo": {
        "containerName": "loans",
        "assetType": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "contentServiceId": 19655,
      "siteId": 3521,
      "containerInfo": {
        "containerName": "mortgage",
        "assetType": 2
      }
    }
  ],
  "enabledContainers": [
    {
      "containerName": "bank",
      "assetType": 1
    },
    {
      "containerName": "credits",
      "assetType": 2
    },
    {
      "containerName": "stocks",
      "assetType": 1
    },
    {
      "containerName": "loans",
      "assetType": 2
    },
    {
      "containerName": "mortgage",
      "assetType": 2
    }
  ],
  "baseUrl": "http://www.tdcanadatrust.com",
  "loginForms": [],
  "isHeld": false,
  "isCustom": false,
  "mfaType": {
    "typeId": 4,
    "typeName": "SECURITY_QUESTION"
  },
  "mfaCoverage": "FMPA",
  "siteSearchVisibility": true
}
```

Comment: We have tested this particular site on TestDrive and it seems like TestDrive needs to be fixed. Thank you for providing feedback, while fixing this might take some time. I would suggest you to either add it through FastLink provided on developer info tab once you'll click on MyProfile link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for providing your feedback. We have tested this particular site on TestDrive and it seems like TestDrive needs to be fixed, while fixing the Test Drive tool might take some time. I would suggest you to either add it through FastLink provided recently added within Test Drive tool. That should help you.